How to use .any method in an if statement in Ruby and capture the variable that matched
I am evaluating for the software I am working on a simple scripting language. I've mapped out what I need for Python but I'm just trying Ruby since it was recommended to me as a simple language. Some of my users will not be programmers.
I am trying to capture the matched variable in this any? method
I assign "match" to x and it will capture the variable. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?
add = [1, 2, 3, 4]
if add.any?{|x| x == 1}
  puts x
end

I can do it in Python like this:
add = [1, 2, 3, 4]
if any((match := x) == 1 for x in add):
    print("x")


Your Python and Ruby code does different things. In Python, you print the string "x" if any match is found. In Ruby, you try to print the contents of the x variable which is out of scope and thus undefined at that time. The same would happen in Python when trying to print(x).

The actual solution depends on what data you have exactly and what you want to do with it. You could do something like x = add.find { |x| x == 1 } to get the first value on the add array which is 1. Or select to get an array of all matching values, or a lot of other options...

You could use the detect method in ruby which does the similar job.
add = [1, 2, 3, 4]
if (x = add.detect{|x| x == 1})
  puts x
end


To check if a given value exists within array using include?:
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

x = 1  
if array.include?(x)
  puts x 
end

In case, we need to lookup more than one item, & (or intersection) is used to perform intersection(find common values) between two arrays.
x = [ 2, 3 ]

matches = array & x

matches.each do |match|
  puts match
end


In Ruby, the block variable x (object inside the block) within the any? method is scoped to the block itself. Therefore it cannot be accessed outside of that block. As a result, you cannot simply capture the block variable x and utilise it outside of the block like you might in Python with the walrus operator (:=). You can do it like this:
add = [1, 2, 3, 4]
match = nil
add.any? { |x| match = x if x == 1 }
puts match

